# How do you use Wordpress MU Domain Mapping to change a subdomain blog to it's own domain?

Tags: wordpress

After creating a network as described on the official [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) and installing the [Wordpress MU Domain Mapper Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/), using recommended settings and making amendments and additions to files where necessary.

I then created a new secondary site(subdomain). Now the `main.co.za` and `sec.main.co.za` are existent and both dashboards work, but the user has to log in again when logging into the `sec.main.co.za` linking from `main.co.za`. I belive this is standard and the browser won't allow persistent connections / cookie sessions between different urls.

Everything appears to be fine except I have registed `sec.co.za` and would like that to be the address oh `sec.main.co.za` home. How can this be achieved?

Are the settings within 'domain mapping' in tools the secondary site? Should I change it under Domains in Settings of "Network Administrator"? or should I change the URL of the site under the "sites"->"all sites" within network administrator.

Let me know of the best practise.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running as Network Administrator, make sure the following are selected in "Domain Mapping":

- Remote Login
- Permanent redirect (better for your blogger's pagerank)
- User domain mapping page
- Redirect administration pages to site's    original domain (remote
  login disabled if this redirect is disabled)

Now instead of the network admin, making a mistake with the site id and entering the wrong entry under domains. Let the admin of the specific site logon, go to `tools->domain mapping` and simple type in the URL of the domain the user requires.

Also make sure the IP address is entered correctly under network, in network administrator. If you have a dynamic IP for some reason, make sure you use a CNAME/ANAME